# Voltage divider. Very Basic Question

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

[image: Voltage Divider]

So in this basic voltge divider in order calculate \$U_4\$ I wrote \$U_4/U = R_A/R\$ .
However looking the correct expression is \$U_4/U= R_A/R_B\$.
While I see the second is correct, I dont see why mine is not... How should I properly think about this in order to always write the voltage divider expressions correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume \$R_A = R_3||R_4\$, and \$R_B = R_2+R_A\$.

- The voltage across \$R_1\$, is the same as the voltage across the series combination of \$R_2\$ and \$R_A\$.
- \$R_1\$ doesn't affect the voltage dropped across the series combination of \$R_2\$ and \$R_A\$.

So you have to think only about how the voltage will now be divided between \$R_2\$ and \$R_A\$. ie., why the second expression is the right one for \$U_4\$.
$$\frac{U_4}{U}=\frac{R_A}{R_2+R_A}=\frac{R_A}{R_B}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram indicates that: -

$$R_B = R_2 + R_3||R_4$$

Hence, if you follow it through,

$$\dfrac{U_4}{U}= \dfrac{R_3||R_4}{R_B}$$

And, given that \$R_A\$ appears to equal \$R_3||R_4\$,

$$\dfrac{U_4}{U}= \dfrac{R_A}{R_B}$$

Answer (score 0):

They have already answered your question @Andyaka and @mitu . I can just tell you how I usually approach any such question.

1)So to start with,  will U<sub>4</sub> depend on R<sub>1</sub>?
For better understanding I added a new circuit , look at it and ask yourself whether value of R<sub>1</sub> affect current through any other resistor?
Reason for that is when we have an ideal voltage source , the potential drop across the resistor will be constant. If you connect 100 resistors parallel to a voltage source , all the resistor will have a same potential drop which will be value of battery/voltage('U' in your question) source you used.

2)Now if you are clear that R<sub>1</sub> in  your question will not affect U4. Then ask the next question , will other resistors affect or are they like R<sub>1</sub>?

R<sub>2</sub>,R<sub>3</sub> and R<sub>4</sub> in your circuit will affect the voltage U4. To understand this assume a current if flowing through R<sub>2</sub>, that will split and one component will flow through R<sub>3</sub>  and other component will flow through R<sub>4</sub>. But we know that R<sub>3</sub> , R<sub>4</sub> are in parallel so it will have same voltage drop. So we take as R<sub>3</sub> // R<sub>4</sub>. Now redraw the circuit as a voltage source with 2 resistors in series , look at the second image. Since current will be same through R<sub>2</sub> and R<sub>3</sub>//R<sub>4</sub>. We know that U = i*[R<sub>2</sub> + R<sub>3</sub>//R<sub>4</sub>] = i*R<sub>B</sub>.
Now you can just calculate the current and find the voltage you are looking for(U4).
U4 = (U/R<sub>B</sub>) * R<sub>A</sub>
[image: 1)]
[image: 2)]